# Are operas considered literature on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am asking specifically about the plots or stories of the works (rather than the music).

Example question about an opera:

- [Had people related the work of Gogol before "The Nose"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/502/17)

Comment: Ask an opera question and see what happens!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is setting a precedent without connection to any question on the site. Let's not operate in thin air.

Comment: @HDE There is one on the main site now. 2 UVs, no DVs or VTCs so far.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's not actually about an opera per se, though. It's basically just about Gogol's stories using the opera as a starting point. I'd hesitate to use that question for a solid argument for/against operas as a whole.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

Because why wouldn't they be? Plays are - we already have questions about [william-shakespeare](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare) - and both operas and plays are works of literature, despite being written for performances.

Comment: Additionally, I'm fairly confident that the musical score, being pertinent to the analysis and understanding of the opera, should also necessarily be on-topic.

Comment: @Emrakul Da...wuuuut?

Comment: @Christian You can't just look at the words of an opera if you want to understand the text. The musical composition of an opera is _part of_ the text.

Comment: Then just rename the thing "Analysis of all kinds of stuff ever created" already.

Comment: @Christian Well, I'd like to see _anyone_ conduct a thorough, rigorous, _and_ meaningful investigation of an opera by only looking at its words and entirely ignoring the music. So if that's what it takes so that looking at the score of an opera no longer offends the sensibilities, then yes.

Comment: "Why wouldn't they be" I don't know, *you* have to give your own arguments for it.